# How to use a vector of deques of a parameterized class in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, deque

I'm trying to use a vector of deques of a custom class. I've got this:

```
std::vector<std::deque<ParamClass<Type1,Type2>>> lines;
```

Where `ParamClass` is a parameterized class with two class parameters. The above line is in the header (as a private variable) of another class. The constructor of that class doesn't do anything to variable `lines`.

Later on in the code I try:

```
std::cout << lines.at(0).size() << std::endl;
```

This should print 0 (as nothing has been added to the deques in the vector. However, I'm getting a segfault. Do I have to somehow "initialize" the deques or something?

Comment: Are you sure the vector isn't empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing element 0 but you haven't added anything so at(0) tries to access illegal memory

You need to make sure lines.size() > 0 first

Comment: A small refinement: it would not access illegal memory, `at()` throws an out_of_range exception.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this. Thanks, will accept in a few minutes.